# What's the jQuery event for scrolling the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove a class `focus-mode` when the user scrolls the page either with the mouse wheel or the scroll bar:

```
$("#input-content").on("SCROLLING_EVENT", function(e) {
  $(".chapter-form").toggleClass("focus-mode");
});
```

But I couldn't find anything about that online. Does jQuery have a scrolling event? If not, what's the best to achieve what I want?

Comment: `$("#input-content").scroll(function(){....});` see here: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/ Also note that this event fires for *every single pixel* scrolled, so your `focus-mode` class will be toggled potentially thousands of times on each scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's plain old `"scroll"`.

```
.on( "scroll", handler )
```

Quoting the [.scroll() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) :

> This method is a shortcut for .on( "scroll", handler ) in the first
>   and second variations, and .trigger( "scroll" ) in the third.

Answer (score 1):

Use [scroll event](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) like,

```
$(function(){
    $('#input-content').scroll(function(e) {
        $(".chapter-form").toggleClass("focus-mode");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
     $(".chapter-form").toggleClass("focus-mode");
});
```

This code triggers every time you scroll.